# Compilation error for @Valid after migrating from spring boot lower to higher version

Tags: spring-boot

I recently migrated from from Spring Boot lower (2.1.7.RELEASE) to higher version (2.5.5) got compilation error in existing code for @Valid annotation which was compiling fine earlier started showing compile error for import statements like import javax.validation.Valid;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new version upgrade of spring-boot the @Valid (javax.validation.Valid) is no longer available implicitly, instead add the following dependency org.springframework.boot /spring-boot-starter-validation in pom.xml, which resolved the issue.